# what is the difference? Why the first one give me an error?

Tags: python

1)

```
d=dict(input().split())
```

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

2)

```
n=int(input())

d = dict(input().split() for _ in range(n))
```

Comment: Did you try `print(input().split())` versus `print(input().split() for _ in range(n))`?

Comment: What's the input? The first one gives `dict` a list; the second one gives it a *sequence* of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call dict() with an iterable it expects that iterable to return **pairs of values**, that it can use as keys and values to create the dict. So, these examples are all valid:

```
dict([('key', 'value'), ('other_key', 'other_value')])
dict(['ab', 'bc', 'dd'])  # 'ab' is pretty much equivalent to a list ['a', 'b']
dict([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])
dict(['key value'.split(), 'other_key other_value'.split()])
```

So, number one would work if you input character pairs, like `aa bb cc`. It will not work for any other case.

Second one will make inputs iterable, which is pretty much the same as wrapping it in a list. It will work for any input value that can be split into a pair. These would be valid:

```
key value
other_key other_value
aa
```

These would be invalid (not pairs):

```
key value other_value
a
aaa
```

So it all depends on the input.